# How can I get a list of pending invitations for a user using django-invitations?

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-invitations

I can see in the [source code for django-invitations](https://github.com/jazzband/django-invitations/blob/master/invitations/managers.py) that there is a manager with an `all_valid` method but I'm having trouble connecting the dots back to `request.user`.

I'm also using django-allauth.

Comment: Seem you can use `Invitation.objects.all_valid().filter(email__iexact=request.user.email, accepted=False)`

Comment: Thanks! That didn't work for me but using `inviter` did (I got the attribute name from the field name in the admin section) `Invitation.objects.all_valid().filter(inviter=request.user, accepted=False)`. Where did you see `email__iexact` would work? (I'm just looking to learn how to solve my own problems in the future :-D )

Comment: Oh `email` was on the [invitation model](https://github.com/jazzband/django-invitations/blob/master/invitations/models.py#L22). I thought you were looking for invitations sent **for** the current user, instead of invitations sent **by** the current user :)

Comment: Ahh, yes. That makes sense. Did you want to create the answer and I'll make it as accepted? Or I'll answer my own question :-D

Comment: Ok I'll add an answer

Comment: @Ben Start [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/) to learn more about the basics of writing database queries with django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this if you want to get invitations sent for the current user:

```
Invitation.objects.all_valid().filter(
    email__iexact=request.user.email, accepted=False,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of invitations sent by the user, that are still pending, use:

```
from invitations.models import Invitation
Invitation.objects.all_valid().filter(inviter=request.user, accepted=False)
```